# Is there a way to separate a Column in a Data File that contains a Column with both Data and Time

Tags: c, database, import

So I'm importing a Data file that contains 5 columns such as

1992-01-25T00:00:30.000Z|0.718|-0.758|-0.429|1.129

I know that `scanf()` allows you to specify the data type it is scanning, like in this case it would be `%s` and `%f`. But my problems is for the first Column I would like to `scanf` it as an number or split that column into two columns like so 1992-01-25|00:00:30.000. Is using `fgets()` another alternative?

Is there a way I can do this efficiently because I'm storing each column into arrays and then I have a search function for each Array and it will be a pain to search an Array containing Strings.

Comment: what does a line of data actually look like

Comment: /*1992-01-25T00:00:30.000Z   0.718   -0.758   -0.429   1.129 */
It has 3 spaces in the between them so what I did was "   " for the token and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fgets`, `strtok`, and `sscanf` to parse the file.

- `fgets` reads a line from the file
- `strtok` breaks the line into substrings using the `|` as a separator
- `sscanf` parses the substrings to convert each substring into numbers

In the sample code below, the date fields are combined into a single integer. For example,
"1992-01-25" becomes the decimal number `19920125`. The time fields are combined so that the final result represents the number of milliseconds from midnight.

```
bool parseFile(FILE *fpin)
{
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpin) != NULL)
    {
        // get the date/time portion of the line
        char *dateToken = strtok(line, "|");

        // extract the floating point values from the line
        float value[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            char *token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            if (token == NULL)
                return false;
            if (sscanf(token, "%f", &value[i]) != 1)
                return false;
        }

        // extract the components of the date and time
        int year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisec;
        char t, z;
        sscanf(dateToken, "%d-%d-%d%c%d:%d:%d.%d%c",
               &year, &month, &day, &t,
               &hour, &minute, &second, &millisec, &z);

        // combine the components into a single number for the date and time
        int date = year * 10000 + month * 100 + day;
        int time = hour * 3600000 + minute * 60000 + second * 1000 + millisec;

        // display the parsed information
        printf("%d %d", date, time);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf(" %6.3f", value[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return true;    // the file was successfully parsed
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to tokenize by space rather than | because the file is separated by space. Would this be implemented with just a " ".

Comment: @YGarcia Yup, if the columns are separated by spaces, then " " will work.

Comment: @ user3386109 I have a question regarding how I could insert this data into a linked list. I have created a function called insert(SortedLinkedList *list, int date,int Time,float rmag,float NSmag,float azmag,float avgmag). I wish to put every line of data into a separate node. But does the declared array of value contain each line or contain a column of each line?

Comment: @YGarcia The array called `value` has the four numbers from one line of input. If I understand the `insert` function correctly then `rmag` is `value[0]`, `NSmag` is `value[1]`, etc.

Comment: Yes that is exactly how it would be inputted. So would I make a  `for` loop to insert every line into the node? Also for the `date` and `time` are they going thru every line as well?

Comment: Yes, and Yes :)

Comment: So how exactly would the `for` loop be setup because the one I came up with wouldn't work `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
  -insert(list1,date,time,value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3]);    
  }` since this wouldn't store all the values that are available would it?

Comment: @YGarcia  I misunderstood. The `while(fgets())` loop already reads every line in the file. The `insert()` function can be called at the end of the loop.

Comment: @ user3386109  OK. That makes sense so just having a normal `insert()` at the end of the while loop will work instead of the `for()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd make a structure that holds the table of data after parsing the file.

```
typedef struct {
   int num_rows;
   char table[MAX_NUM_ROWS][MAX_NUM_COLS][MAX_COL_LEN];
} YOUR_DATA;
```

You should use `fgets` to parse that file, line by line. First tokenize the line on the 'T' and from then on tokenize it on '|', something like this

```
FILE your_fp;
YOUR_DATA yourTable;
char line[MAX_ROW_LEN] = {0};
char *ptr = NULL, field = NULL;
int row = 0, col = 0;
if ((your_fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
   //error
}
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), your_fp) != NULL) {
   ptr = line;
   col = 0;
   if ((field = strsep(&ptr, "T")) != NULL) {
      snprintf(yourTable.table[row][col], MAX_COL_LEN, "%s", field);
      col++;
   }
   while ((field = strsep(&ptr, "|")) != NULL) {
      snprintf(yourTable.table[row][col], MAX_COL_LEN, "%s", field);
      col++;
   }
   row++
}
```

Probably want to keep track of the number of rows in the table etc. Than you can worry about trying to convert them into the correct data type.